# How to find IF single rows meet a criteria ELSE aggregate multiple rows within a group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some accounting data where I need to select a single row within a group if it meets a dollar amount criteria OR if it does not I need to sum/combine multiple rows in that group to see if that group meets the criteria. Example data:

| Continent | Region | Sales Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| South America | North | $300 |
| South America | South | $100 |
| South America | West | $500 |
| South America | East | $200 |
| North America | North | $100 |
| North America | South | $50 |
| North America | West | $50 |
| North America | East | $400 |
| Europe | North | $100 |
| Europe | South | $200 |
| Europe | West | $100 |
| Europe | East | $100 |
| Asia | North | $75 |
| Asia | South | $100 |
| Asia | West | $100 |
| Asia | East | $100 |
| Africa | North | $500 |
| Africa | South | $700 |
| Africa | West | $100 |
| Africa | East | $100 |

In the above example, I want to find all continents that have single regions/rows with $500 in sales OR I want to find countries where 2 or more regions can be combined to meet the $500 amount. My expected result would be:

| Continent | Region_1 | Region_2 | Sales Amount_1 | Sales Amount_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | West | not applicable | $500 |  |
| USA | North,East | not applicable | $500 |  |
| Europe | North,South,West,East | not applicable | $500 |  |
| Asia | does not meet criteria | not applicable | does not meet criteria |  |
| Africa | South | North | $700 | $500 |

Region_2 is only applicable if more than one region within a continent meets the sales amount criteria of $500 on its own.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  And why are there two sales amount columns?

Comment: Thanks for removing the inconsistent tags, was just trying to cast a wider net. Adapting sql syntax between databases is fairly easy/trivial.

If you read my post, you should understand why there are 2 sales columns. The names of the columns are unique with appended _1 and _2 because I want to account for 2 records potentially meeting the criteria without creating two rows in the output.

Comment: So what should happen if 3 rows (that is what tables  have, not records), or more  meet the criteria.  Hint: Do not cast a wider net, it is likely to get question ignored. Also if you think switching databases is *fairly easy/trivial*; well you need to think again.

Comment: I only included 2 sets of fields because that is my requirement. If there are more than that they do not need to be added/parsed. Sorry you are so perturbed by my comment and feel the need to lecture. I am speaking from experience. I think adapting a design pattern from one database syntax to another can be straightforward in many cases. There are exceptions of course, with some limitations in certain databases, but I constantly find solutions in one syntax and am able to adapt them to another. And records are definitely a suitable/interchangeable name for rows, expand your mind.